# All hard drives vanish in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, storage

The title says it, but here's some more detail. All my hard drives (any mounted volumes, actually) suddenly vanish from my computer. For this period of time, I can browse directories, open files, etc. as normal, using Explorer. The rest of the computer functions normally as well. However, software takes upwards of 10 minutes to open (like Blender or Daemon Tools. Visual Studio. Whatever.) Mind you, this is on SSDs or speedy quick hard drives. It seems like it's able to sequentially read as normal, but there's a huge amount of latency (like 5 - 10 minutes) when actually asking the drive to start reading. I don't know much about hard drives / SSDs, so take that with a grain of salt.

Windows Disk Utility also refuses to open during this period of time. Did I mention that the disks come back on their own and work flawlessly again? There's these periods of time where the volumes disappear and then reappear. When they're gone, the computer is not usable. I checked the SMART status of all the drives, and they're fine.

Task manager loses track of the drives, too. Here's what it *should* look like:
[task manager with disks happily existing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNXwy.png)

And here's what it looks like when the mounted volumes fall into the abyss: [task manager not showing any disks existing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il0VH.png). It takes a very long time for task manager to open when this happens.

I checked the windows Event Viewer for any possible relevant information, and it doesn't seem to contain anything useful. I've restarted the computer, and it didn't help.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Go to power options > advanced power settings > hard disk and verify that "turn off the hard disk after" is set to 0.

Comment: Hmm. It wasn't set to zero. However, this just started occurring today, and my computer has been on the same power plan/had the same power settings for months. Guess I'll wait and see, though.

Comment: Considering it happens to all drives, this points to a Windows issue. You could use a restore point to go back to a time when it was working and see if that helps.

Comment: Did you check smart values with smartmontools or CrystalDiskInfo?

Comment: Could be that the drives are randomly not powered and therefore disappear. You should try to replace the PSU SATA power cable and see if this solves the issue